# How to convert list to map which have two map inside

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

This

`[%{id: 6, title: "d"}, %{id: 5, title: "d"}]`

list  have two map inside . Who can I convert  this list to map like this

`%{id: 6, title: "d"}, %{id: 5, title: "d"}`

Comment: The desired format is not valid Elixir. It is to some extent, but there are two maps, exactly as it was in the source list. Please restate your question.

Comment: hello   @mudasobwa how to iterate through a list so i can get only maps

Comment: With any of [`Enum`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#content) iterators. You definitely should start with reading an Elixir intro, not with asking questions on SO.

Comment: @mudasobwa i have try  Enum.into but it give  argument error. i have have read the doc also i have no idea.

Comment: Can you clarify what the expected output should be. You have two maps with a comma between them. Do you want a single map? Have a look at `Map.merge/2` in that case. Possibly in combination with `Enum.reduce/3`, if you have a variable number of maps in your input list.

Answer (score 2):

I will post it here, though, just for the sake of future readers. To iterate a list in Elixir one does:

```
[%{id: 6, title: "d"}, %{id: 5, title: "d"}]
|> Enum.each(fn %{id: id, title: title} ->
               IO.puts "id is: #{id}, title is: #{title}"
             end)
#⇒ id is: 6, title is: d
#⇒ id is: 5, title is: d
```

Comment: This won't convert the input list into anything, which the question asked about. It iterates, but only for the side-effect of printing.

Comment: I did. They say nothing about printing. `Enum.each/2` is not the first thing to reach for in Elixir, since it is only of use for side-effects, so it shouldn't be the first suggestion to a beginner.

Comment: @MartinSvalin “`Enum.each/2` is not the first thing to reach for in Elixir, since it is only of use for side-effects”—this is nothing but your opinion, that even might be right to some extent.